# whats the most sensible way of keeping the current user when using mobile auth on login?

Tags: django, authentication, django-sessions, multi-factor-authentication

I want mobile auth on login, but am wondering what the best way would be to store the current user, before giving them a session id (which would be granted on successful mobile auth).

does it make sense to store a jwt in cookies for the user after they enter their password, while they're on the 2fa auth page? I've looked at a few sites with 2fa, and cant see any that do this, so figure there must be a better way?

Comment: 1. are you using any specific authentication middleware? 2. why giving a session id to the user should be done after mobile auth? an anonymous user owns a session I think

Comment: just the base Django SessionAuthentication. 
 because if I give them the session Id before the mobile auth, they could surely bypass using the auth entirely? unless I store whether the user has passed 2fa, and only allow access for user who have?

Comment: initially, a user doesn't need a session, unless you have data for him to store on the server, like login state. I don't have an answer for you. but if you've not seen this package yet, take a look now. https://pypi.org/project/django-two-factor-auth/